# Why do I only sometimes get an OAuth 2 consent dialog?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0

I just wanted to check my understanding here.

When I log into some applications e.g. Dropbox with my Google account, I get a consent dialog:
[image]

I can then revoke access in my Google account as I would expect.

However, when I sign into other apps e.g. SoundCloud, I don't get a consent dialog at all, it just takes me straight in. Neither does SoundCloud appear in my list of revocable apps in my Google account.

I am presuming that this is because SoundCloud does not require any information or rights with respect to my Google Account and therefore no consent is required. That is, all it requires is authentication, which does not require consent (presumably because entering your credentials is considered consent enough for this purpose).

I just wanted to confirm that I am correct in my assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have found the answer to your question.

If you check Dropbox's login request, it contains a special scope value `https://www.google.com/m8/feeds` which stands for Mange your contacts ([reference](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes)).

Dropbox scope parameter - `scope=https://www.google.com/m8/feeds+email+profile`

But if you check the same with SoundCloud, you only see profile specific scopes such as `email profile openid`

Soundcloud scope parameter - `scope=email profile openid https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me`

So yes, you get the consent page because of the special scope present in Dropbox authorization request. And consent page matches with scope value.

Further read [this blog](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/updates-to-end-user-consent-for-3rd) on default scopes and special scopes.

p.s - You can monitor these scope values with browser debugger. You must enable debugger for popups and navigations to see them. I used chrome to extract those values.